# Lapack undefined reference

Tags: c++, fortran, ubuntu-14.04, undefined-reference, lapack

I'm not sure if it's the right place to ask this but :

I have a problem using lapack, I get "undefined reference to `dsteqr_' " during compilation ("c++  -llapack -lblas TP6.cpp -o TP6")
How can I fix this ?

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

extern "C"
void dsteqr_( char * , int *, double [], double [], double [], int *, double [],
int *  ) ; 

void  tridiag( int n, double d[], double e[], double z[] ) 
{
    int info ; // diagnostic
    double work[2*n-2] ; 
    char compz='v' ; 

    dsteqr_( &compz, &n, d, e, z, &n, work, &info ) ;
    if ( info == 0 ) cout << "La diagonalisation s'est bien passée" << endl ;
    else cout << "Attention ! SSTEQR : info =" << info << endl ;
}

double V(double x){
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    int n=100;
    double d[n], e[n-1], z[n*n], x[n], v[n], L = 5, delta_x = L/n;
    ofstream of1("eigenvalues.dat"), of2("eigenvectors.dat");
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        for (int j=0; i<n; j++){
            if (i == j) z[i+n*j] = 1;
            else z[i+n*j] = 0;
        }
        x[i] = (i+0.5)*delta_x - 0.5*L;
        v[i] = V(x[i]);
        d[i] = 2/pow(delta_x, 2) + v[i];
        if (i==n-2) break;
        e[i] = -1/pow(delta_x, 2);
    }
    tridiag(n,d,e,z);
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++){
        of1 << d[i] << endl;
        for (int j=0; j<n; j++){
            of2 << z[i+n*j];
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try `c++ TP6.cpp -o TP6 -llapack -lblas` instead.

Comment: Bingo, thanks. Why does the order count ? Also if you can spot why I get a segmentation fault...

Comment: If you're linking static libs the linker will drop any names that haven't been referenced in the chain up to that point. As for the segfault, use a debugger, you'e probably reading off the end of one the arrays or using uninitialised data.

Comment: @mwa1 by default, the GNU linker only does a single pass over the libraries in order. You can request multiple passes with `--start-group` etc.

Comment: @user657267 Why don't you make this an answer?