# "undefined reference to `dgesvx_'" although LAPACK is installed and located

Tags: linux, fortran, gfortran, lapack

I'm trying to run a fortran script that includes the function dgesvx(). I ran the script as
`gfortran -lblas -llapack -o cft numtype.o cfapprox.o cftest.o`

and the output is

`gfortran -lblas -llapack -o cft numtype.o cfapprox.o cftest.o   /usr/bin/ld: cfapprox.o: in function` __taylor_cf_approx_MOD_pade_coef':
cfapprox.f90:(.text+0x3c4): undefined reference to `dgesvx_' collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status make: *** [Makefile:18: cft] Error 1`

I'm running Ubuntu on WSL.

I installed multiple libraries that have blas and lapack and when I compile It locates the lapack library.

Comment: For linking the order of the files matters. What happens if you put the libs  last?

Comment: Now I am at a proper keyboard amazingly I can't quickly find a duplicate, though on reflection there might be two reasons - one or possibly both of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33883215/lapack-undefined-reference ( see the comments )  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20669410/gfortran-lapack-undefined-reference-error might help. But please tell us what happens if you try `gfortran cfapprox.o cftest.o -o cft -llapack -lblas`

Comment: This worked for me thank you! doing `gfortran cfapprox.o cftest.o -o cft -llapack` worked.

Answer (score 0):

Amazingly I can't quickly find a duplicate to this. But the answer is hidden in the comments to [Lapack undefined reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33883215/lapack-undefined-reference) Quoting from there "If you're linking static libs the linker will drop any names that haven't been referenced in the chain up to that point" and "by default, the GNU linker only does a single pass over the libraries in order. You can request multiple passes with `--start-group`". Putting this together

```
gfortran cfapprox.o cftest.o -o cft -llapack -lblas
```

Solves this particularly case, and as a general rule of thumb put all libraries you want to link against at the *end* of the link line.

While I am here note the lapack and blas libraries that come with most Linuces are not optimised - you will probably get better performance if you install and link against [openblas](https://www.openblas.net/) instead - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36483054/install-openblas-via-apt-get-sudo-apt-get-install-openblas-dev) for installation on Ubuntu. You can then simply link against `-lopenblas`. Intel's mkl is another optimised alternative.